# HTML form values into SESSION variable as an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, session

I have a html form with 16 fields (https://secure.high-speed-business-club.com//TEMPLATE-order-form-module/?affiliate=0).

What is the best way to capture all of these field values in a single array to be stored as SESSION variables?

Comment: `$_SESSSSION['form']=$_POST;` (or $_GET) if you **really** want to

Answer (score -2):

In order to do this you will have to post your form data to a second page and assign your session variables there.

Once they're assigned you will be able to access them anywhere on the site as long as that session is active.

[W3 School's tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)